# SQL Server & RStudio - SQL Connection Almost Working

Tags: sql, sql-server, rstudio, ssms

I've been running into an issue in R Studio with a SQL connection.
We've had an on-prem SQL Server that's been upgraded over the years, and a colleague that set it up no longer is with the organization.
We also have an Azure Server that's loaded with a SQL Server as well that was much more recently set up before they departed.

We have a GUI program we're currently developing, and one of the early steps is a SQL Login connection for the user where the variable is declared (db_user) and changes with their login and passes the password correctly within system variables defined in .Renviron as posted on RStudio's site for references.

Our initial connection string looks like this, and this is the line of code that starts the connection and where I believe the issue may lie first:

```
db_conn_onprem <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
  Driver = "SQL Server",
  Server = Sys.getenv("server"),
  Database = Sys.getenv("database"),
  UID = Sys.getenv("db_user"),
  PWD = Sys.getenv("PWD")
```

Whenever the Azure connection succeeds, it connects as dbo@Azure\Azure vs On-Prem's guest@Server\Server.
(I can't post in-line screenshots yet)
On-Prem Connection Screenshot: https://i.ibb.co/PmbGt5y/RStudio-SQL.png
Azure Connection Screenshot: https://i.ibb.co/WFY3FqZ/azure1.png

I feel this is something dbo-related since that's where the connection drops.

(variable names anonymized)
Now for the issue:
Whenever we attempt to run a series of queries, our on-prem errors out with this:

```
Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1655: 42000: [Microsoft][SQL Server][SQL Server]Cannot execute as the server principal because the principal "db_user" does not exist, this type of principal cannot be impersonated, or you do not have permission. 
<SQL> 'EXECUTE AS LOGIN = 'db_user' SELECT name FROM master.sys.sysdatabases WHERE dbid > 4 AND HAS_DBACCESS(name) = 1 ORDER BY name ASC'
```

However, run the exact same procedure on the SQL Server in Azure with relatively no major configuration, and it succeeds.

Here's the SQL Code we run:

```
EXECUTE AS LOGIN = 'db_user' SELECT name 
FROM master.sys.sysdatabases 
WHERE dbid > 4 
AND HAS_DBACCESS(name) = 1 
ORDER BY name ASC
```

I feel like I've exhausted my resources for this, first I thought it was the initial R code or possibly SQL Drivers, however I don't believe that to be the issue since the SQL driver pulls a list of names in R Studio in the Connections context menu, but bounces back the error when attempting to complete the query.

Whenever I'm searching errors for references for this error, I see

```
Cannot execute as the server principal because the principal "dbo" does not exist, this type of principal cannot be impersonated, or you do not have permission.
```

Listed as the most commonly related error for the one I'm experiencing, however I've tried a number of those (From blank DB ownerships to unrelated solutions), but I've mostly hit a wall here.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: FYI, `sysdatabases` is a deprecated view from SQL Server **2000**; you should really be using `sys.databases` now.

Comment: @Larnu I've definitely used that statement before in SSMS, however for some reason it isn't recognized in RStudio SQL queries for some reason. It specifically likes that version of `master.sys.sysdatabases` call. I've prior tried updating that specific line and RStudio does not like it when I do that.

While it succeeds in SSMS just fine, however R Studio is much different and errors out with `"Incorrect syntax near '.'.  [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. "`

Answer (score 0):

> I feel this is something dbo-related since that's where the connection drops, but I have no clue where to continue going on this issue.

Yep.

This

```
EXECUTE AS LOGIN = 'db_user'
```

requires [impersonate permission](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/grant-server-principal-permissions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#a-granting-impersonate-permission-on-a-login) for the login.  Which the error message is clearly telling you.  It's unclear why you want to impersonate that login instead of simply connecting as the login to begin with.

Comment: That was another developer's initial connection fil that I picked up the work on.
In R Studio (For Testing), the connection & SQL Driver statements connect to the server before the DB List query is executed, and it's even shown there prior the SQL statements in the screenshots.

I'm attempting to find the answer as to why the Azure SQL Instance can be utilized with the same scripts, and with the same user accounts having the same levels of permission (Meaning very little accounts if any are granted Impersation permission).

Comment: Impersonation behaves the same on Azure SQL Database.

Comment: Correct, however it's the fact that it's succeeding on our Azure-side with as far as I know, very little customization vs the on-prem SQL Server that could have an option or two modified that's blocking the same connection.

Comment: Updated OP to be a bit more in-sequence for how RStudio & SQL interact, or at least how this portion of the connection is being developed since it's running within it's own app outside of R Studio.

Comment: Also Azure SQL Database doesn't support `EXECUTE AS LOGIN`.  If this is just SQL Server on an Azure VM, then it's exactly the same product as on-prem.

Comment: Correct, this is just a SQL Server in Azure that is running on top of a Datacenter OS due to having other industry programs as dependencies in addition to the SQL portion.